# S3 versioning - why leave an expired delete marker behind?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm adding a lifecycle rule for a versioned bucket, and I'm confused about this:

[image]

Specifically, the "remove expired object delete marker" option. Why would one *not* want to remove that? If I have an object with just one version, and I delete that object/version, five days later it will be permanently deleted. Then there's a delete marker hanging around pointing to nothing, so what's the point of keeping it?

Comment: Maybe as a sort of delete-log so you know what has been deleted? Does seem pretty useless though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon S3 will not **automatically** delete expired object delete markers. The lifecycle policy provides a means to do so.

Deleting the last version of an object that has a delete marker **will merely delete the object**. It does not trigger an action on S3 to determine whether there are any expired delete markers. So, yes, the lifecycle rule is worth implementing if the bucket is versioned and versions of objects are often deleted.

Comment: I get that, but why would someone want to not have the lifecycle rule not remove the expired delete marker? What's the point of leaving a delete marker when all versions have been deleted? (the delete marker actually takes up space: the # of bytes in the object's name)

Comment: I agree, there's probably no point. That's why they added the opportunity, since S3 won't remove it when the last useful version is removed.

Comment: @ffxsam Why? Two words: backwards compatibility.  S3 has done a phenomenal job of introducing new features without breaking anything.  The ability to delete old versions was introduced long before [the ability to delete old delete markers was](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-lifecycle-management-update-support-for-multipart-uploads-and-delete-markers/) and therefore it's a separate option in order to avoid unexpected behavior changes for users who had selected one option before the other option existed.  You aren't missing something, there's generally no need to leave them behind any more.

Comment: Thanks for all the info guys.. this has been super confusing for me too.